# How Can I Made conditional form?

Tags: blogger

I want to make search form.
Which have 3 categories with conditional logic.
1. Car make like - Honda
2. Car model like - civic
3. Car variant like -typeR

So all these depend on pervious one.

In first column; there are car brands list.
Then when you click on any brand then show its models list in second one. Then when you select any model then in last one; shows thier variants.

This type of conditional form. I want to make?

How it’s made and use in blogger.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".submenu > a").click(function() {
  $(this).next("ul").toggle();
});
```

```css
.submenu ul {display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
  <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Honda</a>
    <ul>
     <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Civic</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/p/type-r.html">Type R</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```